# "Redundant" Move Operations to same Register in Cuda

Tags: assembly, cuda, ptx

I was viewing the CUDA SASS code, and I noticed a large amount of move operations to the same registers. Ex:

```
172           MOV R3, R3;
173           MOV R4, R4;
174           MOV R3, R3;
175           MOV R4, R4;
176           MOV R4, R4;
177           MOV R3, R3;
178           MOV R4, R4;
```

I'm just curious, what's the purpose of these move operations? Is it for timing, and they act like 'nop's or is it something less obvious?

Note: these are not included in the PTX code, just the SASS. I and assume are used in-between operations, not during a PTX operation. Although, for context, the PTX is:

```
85  .reg .u32 a, b; 
86  bfind.s64 a, %rd37;
```

The actual `c++` code is an inline assembly of the ptx above.

**Update:**
Compiled using `sm_52`, `compute_52` and `x64` in Visual Studio 2013 with Cuda Toolkit 7.5. Device: GTX 970 (Maxwell GPU).

Switching from `Debug` to `Release` removes this inefficiency.

Comment: Are optimizations enabled? How do you compile? What device do you use?

Comment: Compiled using the 7.5 toolkit with Visual Studio 2013 (c++). I should also mention that the PTX code was used in-line assembly. compute_20, sm_20, Maxwell GPU (gtx 970). Optimizations: "/Od"

Comment: Also, just tried this with "/Ox", no change to that section of assembly...

Comment: Well, you are compiling with optimizations disabled. Disregard both, PTX and SASS. It's a mess in debug mode. Also note, that in your case, SASS generated for sm_20 will not be used, instead PTX will be compiled on runtime into Maxwell-specific SASS.

Comment: Have you enabled optimizations for the host compiler only? It will not change  optimization level for CUDA code. You should add `-O3` to `nvcc` flags. Or, better, use predefined "Release" configuration for Visual Studio project. By the way, how do you retrieve SASS?

Comment: That removed them. So essentially they're just junk operations by debug/not optimizing...? Interesting...

Comment: Hard to say. Neither SASS instruction sets, nor CUDA debuggers internals are particularly well documented by Nvidia, but it, probably, has something to do with debuggers, yes.

Comment: For GTX 970 you would want to use `sm_50` not `sm_20`. Without buildable code to reproduce this, one can't diagnose this issue. Note that all 64-bit integer operations are emulated on the GPU, which is a 32-bit device; it's possible there are inefficiencies introduced by the emulation, but without the full program context it is impossible to say one way or the other.